# XSLT expression to check if HTML element exists

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to test to see if a HTML element exists within XSLT but cannot get it to work. I am currently trying to assign a variable based on whether it can find it like this:

```
    <xsl:variable name="TestParaText">  
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(smf:body,index[@id='testSpan'])">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Element found'"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'Element Not Found'"/>                    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

Within my HTML I have this:

```
<span id="testSpan" style="display:none"></span>
```

I do not want the element to be visible so I have set a style attribute, but I am pretty sure its something to do with my poor xpath / XSLT syntax! Apologies, as I am not very knowledgeable on this topic but hopefully I should of provided enough information for someone to help me. Thanks

[image: HTML Body]

Comment: Please have an example input XML.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to get that, I am using a tool to generate the body which is essentially a text editor which generates HTML, and I have just put the span tag in there. If I put a value in within the element it does output so I know it's there, its just how I reference the id of the HTML element within the body

Comment: **1.** Please post your input XML **as code**, not as a picture, so that we can use it for testing. If necessary, use the *identity transform* template to get it. -- **2.** XSLT is very context-dependent, and you are only showing us an isolated part of yours. It's not possible to answer your question exactly without knowing where you are at the moment you need to apply this test.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` function works on strings. If you would like to test if `smf:body` contains a node `index[@id='testSpan']`. You should have something like this:

```
<xsl:when test="body[descendant::index[@id='testSpan2']]">
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although it still does not work using this syntax. Do you know of any other ways of referencing the element?

Comment: Maybe this is because of namespaces. Can you post the generated body?

Comment: Sorry its a bit small (I obviously changed it to testSpan2)

Comment: The node `body` does not belong to any namespace. See my edited answer.

Comment: Still no joy. Although if I use  `<xsl:when test="contains(smf:body,'test string')">` to look for a string it works, so it must be looking in `smf:body`

Answer (score 0):

If below is ur XML

INPUT XML :

```
<span id="testSpan" style="display:none"></span>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test = "@id = 'testSpan'">            
             <TestParaText>
             Exists
             </TestParaText>
 </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
     <TestParaText>
                 Doesnt Exists
     </TestParaText>
        </xsl:otherwise> 
        </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT will be :

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<span>

<TestParaText>
          Exists
</TestParaText>

</span>
```

Please share ur request xml and expected OUTPUT